# $_FILES["file"]["type"] VS pathinfo($file_name, PATHINFO_EXTENSION) how best and what different

Tags: php

**`$_FILES["file"]["type"]` VS `pathinfo($file_name, PATHINFO_EXTENSION)`** how best are these two,and what's difference in both ?

I've asked this question because I found `$_FILES["file"]["type"]` not good with images, and it can't define image type which I take by my D-camera. However the `pathinfo($file_name, PATHINFO_EXTENSION)` can so easily define any type of file, but I see all developers use `$_FILES["file"]["type"]`.

*So please tell me when I should use them and what is good for security purpose.*

Answer (score 4):

You should never rely on `$_FILES["file"]["type"]` (because this data is provided with browser and is not checked by php at all).

Choose either file extension or image type got from [getimagesize](https://www.php.net/getimagesize)

Answer (score 1):

`$_FILES['files']['type']` is actually the file type the browser thinks the file is. It can be interesting, but it can also be unreliable.